# Media content on separate hard drive

Tags: drive, media

I would like to use media content on separate internal hard drive, but would like to access it from the video, music and pics options on desktop where it is usually accessed.

How do I change the folders properties to the new hard drive?

Comment: your question how to change folder link path to different location on your hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in two ways: **symbolic links** and **bind mounts**. The former is easier to setup and from my experience causes less issues with Nautilus. The latter is subjectively more stable and probably faster. If you are not too familiar with Ubuntu and Linux I suggest you to go with the first option.

## Symbolic links

Let's say you already mounted your second hard drive on `/mnt/hdd`. You could create a new directory for your own user for ease of use.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/hdd/username
sudo chown username:username /mnt/hdd/username
```

Where `username` is your system user.

Now create the directories you want on the second harddrive, eg: Downloads and Video

```
mkdir /mnt/hdd/username/{Downloads,Videos}
```

At this point you are ready to create the symbolic link. Delete the `Downloads` and `Videos` folder from your home directory, **if you have any content in them copy it on the new directories on the second hard drive first**. You can use Nautilus for that.

```
rm -rf ~/{Videos,Downloads}
ln -s /mnt/hdd/username/{Videos,Downloads} /home/username/
```

Now you can access the Videos and Downloads directories from your home directory like they were on your primary hard disk.

## Bind mounts

This is a bit more complex solution but it looks more solid to me. I wouldn't suggest you to follow this route if you consider yourself a newbie.

Again let's assume your second hard drive is mounted in `/mnt/hdd`. Create a directory for your user and the media directories like before.

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/hdd/username
sudo chown username:username /mnt/hdd/username
mkdir /mnt/hdd/username/{Downloads,Videos}
```

Now **copy any content in your user's Downloads and Videos folders** to the new locations on the second harddrive and **delete the directories in your home folder**.

Now we need to modify the fstab.

You need to find the UUID of your second hard drive with:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

You'll get the list of all your partitions sorted by UUID. The list will be something like this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 ott  3 20:21 2de34713-f0ee-4a12-9214-21a5431a7b7b -> ../../sdb1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 ott  3 20:21 5467abe5-4732-4594-8d7a-c2db5a2e01f0 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 ott  3 20:21 729efb0c-3f58-40e9-8b85-af62a321e135 -> ../../sda2
```

In this case my second HDD is `sdb1` so I use the `2de34713-f0ee-4a12-9214-21a5431a7b7b` UUID.

It is very likely that your second hard drive will be already listed in the fstab, so find the entry for it

```
sudo nano /etc/fstab
```

It will be something like this:

```
UUID=2de34713-f0ee-4a12-9214-21a5431a7b7b /mnt/hdd       ext4    relatime,errors=remount-ro 0 2
```

If you don't have it you need to add that entry manually, be careful to use the right filesystem (probably ext4 or ext3).

Below that line you can add the bind partitions like so:

```
/mnt/hdd/username/Downloads     /home/username/Downloads    none        bind,rw     0 0
/mnt/hdd/username/Videos        /home/username/Videos       none        bind,rw     0 0
```

Save the changes and restart your system.

## The easy route

You can also change the location of the Nautilus bookmarks like suggested by Mitch, that is definitely simpler but it wouldn't be a system wide change, as various software will continue to use the default directories in the home folder.

Answer (score 0):

To change the path of folders that you need, just open files, click on files on the menu bar, and choose Bookmarks, once the window opens, just change the Location/path to whatever you want.  See images below.

[image]

[image]